# Reset a tree node upon collapse

Tags: extjs4

I have a tree panel whose nodes are loaded dynamically from the server. When the user expands a node, it will load the children for that node from the server and add them to that node. This part is working.

When the user collapses a node, I'd like to remove all the children from that node and "reset" the node so that it can be exanded again.

So far, I have the following in the collapse event handler:

```
function(node){
    node.removeAll(); // remove all child nodes
                      // this causes the expand arrow to disappear

    node.expandable = true;
    // ... now what?
}
```

How do I "reset" the node (the "... now what?") so that the view knows to add the expand arrow back again?

Essentially I'd like the process of collapsing and then re-expanding a node to reload all of the children under that node.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the `loaded` field to `false`. The "expanded" attribute does not need to be changed.

The final solution is:

```
function(node){
    node.removeAll(); // remove all child nodes
    node.set('loaded', false); // tell node it can be expanded again
}
```